# AWS CDK accessing parameters when deploying stacks on the pipeline via yaml, typescript and nodejs

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I'm fairly new to AWS and using the CDK but have been working on a project which deploys to AWS via a pipeline using yaml for the `cf-template` and later a node script to run `cdk deploy` on a set of stack files that have been written in Typescript.

In the `cf-template` yaml where the cdk-toolkit is being defined there's a bucket resource with name `X`. After the toolkit has been created/updated in the pipeline, the `cdk deploy` command is executed to deploy some stacks and workers, which should live in bucket `X`. They aren't automatically being uploaded there however, so I've tried using [the `--parameters` flag](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/parameters.html) to specify `X` as below.

`cdk deploy --toolkit-stack-name my-toolkit --parameters uploadBucketName=X --ci --require-approval never`

When I do this I get the following error in the pipeline for the first stack that gets deployed:

`Parameters: [uploadBucketName] do not exist in the template`

I assumed this meant that in the `MyFirstStack.ts` file it was missing a parameter definition as suggested by the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/parameters.html), but it's not clear to me why this is necessary or how it's supposed to be used when it's the `cdk deploy` command which provides a value for this parameter. I tried adding it per the docs

```
const uploadBucketName = new CfnParameter(this, "uploadBucketName", {
  type: "String",
  description: "The name of the Amazon S3 bucket where uploaded files will be stored."});
```

but not sure if this is really the right thing to do, and it doesn't work besides - I still get the same error.

Does anyone have any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Comment: This is a complex setup.  Don't the standard [Bootstrapping](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/bootstrapping.html) and [CDK Pipeines](https://cdkworkshop.com/20-typescript/70-advanced-topics/200-pipelines.html) workflows work for you?

Comment: @fedonev It is a complex setup! Unfortunately it's a well established project which I wouldn't be permitted to make those kinds of changes to